# SQL Query on finding highest within duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query. If a duplicate SNO+SG Combination is found, we need to pick up the one having the highest value. If no duplicate value is found for a SNO+SG Combination, we will take that as it is. The sample input and output is over here:

[image: Sample here]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will help you get answers if you include your sample data and expected output in your question directly as well as examples of queries you have tried and why they don't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation:

```
select bg, sno, sg, max(value)
from t
group by bg, sno, sg;
```

Comment: I want to check if SNO+SG Combination is occuring more than once or not. If it occurs, only then I need to take max value.

Comment: @Ayn76 this query should do what you are looking for. Please try it.